# Unable to validate TestNG Asserion Scenario

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

Hi i am learning Selenium. my test case is to verify the "Learn SoapUI" link existance under TESTING tab in Guru99 site. When i use **if** condition it gets passed, when i use **Assertion** statement condition gets failed. Plz help mw with code.
**Url:** https://www.guru99.com/
**My Code:**

```
@Test
public void Sample() {

driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/");
List<WebElement> TESTING= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='featured-box cloumnsize1']//ul[1]//li"));
for(int i=0;i<TESTING.size();i++) {
    Assert.assertEquals(TESTING.get(i).getText().equals("Learn SoapUI"), true);
    System.out.println("Learn SoapUI link is present");
//********************************************************************* 
    if(TESTING.get(i).getText().equals("Learn SoapUI")) {
        System.out.println("Learn SoapUI Testing link is in list");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are checking the text of each element in collection. If the the text of the firs element will not **Learn SoapUI** your test will be failed straightway.

The simple way will be to get text of all elements, put them to the List of Strings and check that **Learn SoapUI** contains in this list.

So here is your code with this changes:

```
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/");

    // Getting all elements from the cours 
    List<WebElement> TESTING = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='featured-box cloumnsize1']//ul[1]//li"));

    // Getting text from the each element and putting to List of Strings
    List<String> listSoapCourses = TESTING.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Verification that Learn SoapUI exists in the list of courses
    Assert.assertTrue(listSoapCourses.contains("Learn SoapUI"), "Error message: Learn SoapUI not contains in the list of courses");
```

Comment: it helped me a lot.. could u plz explain the line
    List<String> listSoapCourses = TESTING.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I used streams to get text from each element instead using the loop.
map(WebElement::getText) - this part will get text from each WebElement in stream. 
collect(Collectors.toList()) - will put all String's to the List.

You can use loops if streams to hard by now. 

Loop will be like this:
        List<String> listSoapCourses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WebElement elementInList:TESTING) {
            listSoapCourses.add(elementInList.getText());
        }
    Assert.assertTrue(listSoapCourses.contains("Learn SoapUI"), "Error message...")

Comment: Thank u :) Nice explanation.